# MySQL8 json payload does not accept json string as value for element

Tags: json, stored-procedures, json-deserialization, mysql-8.0, json-table

I have a stored procedure (see stored_procedure_1 code below) that expects json passed as an argument and inserts that data into a table.

---

-- stored_procedure_1:

```
DELIMITER \\

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_test_procedure \\

CREATE PROCEDURE my_test_procedure(my_payload JSON)

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO my_test_table (id, ud)
    SELECT jt.id,
           jt.ud
    FROM JSON_TABLE(my_payload, '$[*]' columns (
        id int path '$.id',
        ud json path '$.ud'
        )) AS jt;
END \\

DELIMITER ;
```

---

-- table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE my_test_table
(
    id int,
    ud varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Calling the procedure with the following call (see call_1 below) that has json string as value for one of the elements gives error (see error_1 response below).

-- call_1:

```
CALL my_test_procedure('[{"id":1,"ud":"{\"1\":5,\"2\":6,\"3\":7}"}]');
```

-- error_1:
Error Code: 3140. Invalid JSON text: "Missing a comma or '}' after an object member." at position 17 in value for column '.my_payload'.

Call with that value as json (see call_2 below) works as expected.

-- call_2:

```
CALL my_test_procedure('[{"id":1,"ud":{\"1\":5,\"2\":6,\"3\":7}}]'); -- OR
CALL my_test_procedure('[{"id":1,"ud":{"1":5,"2":6,"3":7}}]');
```

Looking for suggestions for workarounds within MySQL code (consider the format of the passed payload cannot change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the escaping of `"` inside your string; when the string is interpreted by MySQL, the `\"` is interpreted as `"` (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html)). For example:

```sql
SELECT '[{"id":1,"ud":"{\"1\":5,\"2\":6,\"3\":7}"}]'
```

Output:

```js
[{"id":1,"ud":"{"1":5,"2":6,"3":7}"}]
```

which is not valid JSON. To be valid JSON when interpreted by MySQL, you need an escaped `\` before the `"` (i.e. `\\"`, which MySQL then interprets as `\"`):

```sql
SELECT '[{"id":1,"ud":"{\\"1\\":5,\\"2\\":6,\\"3\\":7}"}]'
```

Output:

```js
[{"id":1,"ud":"{\"1\":5,\"2\":6,\"3\":7}"}]
```

This will then work with your procedure:

```sql
CALL my_test_procedure('[{"id":1,"ud":"{\\"1\\":5,\\"2\\":6,\\"3\\":7}"}]');
SELECT *
FROM my_test_table
```

Output:

```
id  ud
1   "{\"1\":5,\"2\":6,\"3\":7}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, @Nick. I understand better now why my call_1 errors out.

Going back to my statement from the post "Looking for suggestions for workarounds within MySQL code (consider the format of the passed payload cannot change)", do you have suggestions for workaround within MySQL routine (considering the payload format cannot change)?

Comment: @eetaSanglo I'm not sure there is any simple way to work around this short of manually parsing the entire input. But I'm a bit confused as to how you got a string like that to begin with; I would have expected that the source would have given you something with an escaped \ in it. How is the string getting into the MySQL query? Can you share more of the environment you are operating in?

Comment: Thank you, @Nick. An external application passes the payload (in that form). Would have loved the value for the second element to be a json object, unfortunately it is not and trying to explore if there are elegant workarounds.

Comment: How does it get from the external application into your MySQL code?

Comment: The application calls the stored procedure with the payload (computes it in the application and passes it as argument to the stored procedure)

Comment: In that case I would have expected the argument inside the procedure to have an actual `\` character in it, in which case it would be the equivalent of calling with `'[{"id":1,"ud":"{\\"1\\":5,\\"2\\":6,\\"3\\":7}"}]'`.

Comment: @eetaSanglo did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: Thanks for asking, @Nick. Yes, the application devs are now looking to format the payload in either '[{"id":1,"ud":"{\\"1\\":5,\\"2\\":6,\\"3\\":7}"}]' or '[{"id":1,"ud":{"1":5,"2":6,"3":7}}]' form.

Comment: @eetaSanglo good to hear. I'm glad you've managed to get a solution.